# Using declare variables in Oracle

Tags: sql, plsql

I am having a syntax issue with the declaration in Oracle. I am using these variables on MS SQL server and they work just fine; however, how do I declare these in Oracle?

Use in MS SQL server:

```
DECLARE @FROM_DT DATETIME
DECLARE @END_DT  DATETIME
DECLARE @LOCATION  VARCHAR(100)

SET @FROM_DT = '04/01/2011'
SET @END_DT =  '05/09/2011'
SET  @LOCATION ='VA'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot declare variables outside of a PL/SQL block.

The format of variable declarations inside a PL/SQL block is described very detailed in the manual (including examples):

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/fundamentals.htm#CIHGGIAH

Comment: Simple but informative. «Cannot declare variables outside of a PL/SQL block» is the important bit most tutorials omit. Also, other documents explain the `VARIABLE` syntax and do not mention it's a SQL*Plus internal command.

Answer (score 0):

You may pass variables to other sql files. It's not exactly what you want but it helps me to solve some problems without using blocks.

For Instance my config.sql file:

```
@drop.sql 'MY_USER'
```

my drop.sql file:

```
DROP USER "&1" CASCADE;
```